# undefined History object when testing with and react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, history.js, babel-jest, react-testing-library

I have a button that is supposed to do: this.props.history.push(PageA) when clicked.
However, I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` - meaning that history is undefined.

Here is my set up that runs before each test for the Tax comonent

```
const initialState = {
    tax: {
        amount: 0.35
    }
};

function renderWithRedux(
    component,
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ['/app/dashboard'] }),
    store = createStore(***createReducer(history), initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk))
) {
    return {
        ...render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <HelmetProvider>
                    <Router history={history}>
                        <Switch>{component}</Switch>
                    </Router>
                </HelmetProvider>
            </Provider>
        ),
        store,
        history
    };
}
```

*** this is imported from another file :

```
    combineReducers({
        tax: taxReducer,
        router: connectRouter(history)
    });
```

Is there another way to pass the history? Am I missing a point?
Thank you very much for those who will try to help.
Any links with examples or important information will be appreciated :)

react-testing-library: 6.1.2

react version: 16.8.6

npm: 6.9.0